# MySQL best way to select first, second and last value in each group

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL to get first, second and last values in each group in a table. My data rows are like this:

```
userID    purchaseTime
----------------------
1         2018-01-01
1         2018-01-02
1         2018-01-03
1         2018-01-04
2         2018-02-01
2         2018-02-02
3         2018-03-01
```

The expected result would be:

```
userID    first         second        last
------------------------------------------------
1         2018-01-01    2018-01-02    2018-01-04
2         2018-02-01    2018-02-02    2018-02-02
3         2018-03-01    null          2018-03-01
```

After googling for half day, I can only figure out a stupid way that executes the following two queries RESPECTIVELY then merge the results by my server-side code:

```
//get 1st, 2nd values 
SELECT userID, purchaseTime
FROM   purchaseLog t1
WHERE 
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) 
        FROM    purchaseLog t2
        WHERE t2.userID = t1.userID AND 
              t2.purchaseTime<= t1.purchaseTime
    ) <= 2 order by t1.userID , t1.purchaseTime;

//get last value
SELECT max(purchaseTime) FROM purchaseTime GROUP BY userID
```

I'm pretty sure that there must be a more elegant way to get the results in one shot. Can anyone help me to reach my requirement? thank you all!

Comment: I'm confused as to how you get the desired result given that input. So `first` should be the earliest `purchaseTime` for the respective `ID`, `second` should be the middle, and `third` should be the latest? It appears that way for your first row, but your other two rows wouldn't match up with that, so I'm guessing that's not quite what you're looking for?

Comment: It is possible to combine the above in a single query, however I do not think it would be a really efficient one.

Comment: @ObsidianAge
hope this explanation is more clear: in my requirement, if a user has more than 3 purchase logs in the table, then field "last" would be the last purchase time of this user.  If a user has only one purchase log, field "last" would be the same with "first", as there is only one log belongs to this user, so the purchase time is both first and last.

Comment: @ObsidianAge it seems refreshingly clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is untested but should give you a good idea:

```
SELECT
    t1.userID,
    t1.purchaseTime AS first,
    t2.purchaseTime AS `second`,
    t4.purchaseTime AS last
FROM purchaseLog t1
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t0 ON t1.userID = t0.userID AND t0.purchaseTime < t1.purchaseTime
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID AND t1.purchaseTime < t2.purchaseTime
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t3 ON t1.userID = t3.userID AND t1.purchaseTime < t3.purchaseTime
                        AND t3.purchaseTime < t2.purchaseTime
JOIN purchaseLog t4 ON t1.userID = t4.userID AND t1.purchaseTime <= t4.purchaseTime
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t5 ON t1.userID = t5.userID AND t4.purchaseTime < t5.purchaseTime
WHERE t0.purchaseTime IS NULL AND t3.purchaseTime IS NULL AND t5.purchaseTime IS NULL
```

Let me break that down step-by-step:

First, I get all the rows for which no earlier row for the same userID exists:

```
SELECT
    t1.userID,
    t1.purchaseTime AS first
FROM purchaseLog t1
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t0 ON t1.userID = t0.userID AND t0.purchaseTime < t1.purchaseTime
WHERE t0.purchaseTime IS NULL
```

Next, I get all the rows with a purchaseTime greater than the first purchaseTime for which there's no rows with a purchaseTime in-between the two:

```
SELECT
    t1.userID,
    t2.purchaseTime AS `second`
FROM purchaseLog t1
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID AND t1.purchaseTime < t2.purchaseTime
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t3 ON t1.userID = t3.userID AND t1.purchaseTime < t3.purchaseTime
                        AND t3.purchaseTime < t2.purchaseTime
WHERE t3.purchaseTime IS NULL
```

Finally, I get the rows with a purchaseTime greater than or equal to the first for which no greater purchaseTime exists:

```
SELECT
    t1.userID,
    t4.purchaseTime AS last
FROM purchaseLog t1
JOIN purchaseLog t4 ON t1.userID = t4.userID AND t1.purchaseTime <= t4.purchaseTime
LEFT JOIN purchaseLog t5 ON t1.userID = t5.userID AND t4.purchaseTime < t5.purchaseTime
WHERE t5.purchaseTime IS NULL
```

Combine them all into one query to get the answer above.

Comment: thanks a lot for giving me a hint, im going to study it right now! Though it might take me time as im new in mysql, anyways, thank you!

Comment: This is a very clever solution and gave me something i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can probably do this:

Pick individual statements that give you first, second and last then join them together:

```
SELECT a.userID, a.purchaseTime 
    FROM fsl a WHERE a.purchaseTime = 
    (SELECT MAX(b.purchaseTime) FROM fsl b WHERE b.userID = a.userID)

SELECT a.userID, a.purchaseTime 
    FROM fsl a WHERE a.purchaseTime = 
    (SELECT MAX(c.purchaseTime) FROM fsl c 
        WHERE c.purchaseTime < (SELECT MAX(b.purchaseTime) 
            FROM fsl b WHERE b.userID = a.userID));

SELECT a.userID, a.purchaseTime 
    FROM fsl a WHERE a.purchaseTime = 
    (SELECT MIN(b.purchaseTime) 
        FROM fsl b WHERE b.userID = a.userID)
```

and piece it together using JOINS:

```
SELECT fst.userID as userID, fst.purchaseTime as first, snd.purchaseTime as snd, trd.purchaseTime as last FROM
    (SELECT a.userID, a.purchaseTime 
    FROM fsl a 
    WHERE a.purchaseTime = 
        (SELECT MAX(b.purchaseTime) FROM fsl b WHERE b.userID = a.userID)) fst
    JOIN (SELECT a.userID, a.purchaseTime FROM fsl a 
            WHERE a.purchaseTime = (SELECT MAX(c.purchaseTime) 
            FROM fsl c WHERE c.purchaseTime < (SELECT MAX(b.purchaseTime) 
            FROM fsl b WHERE b.userID = a.userID))) snd
    ON fst.userID = snd.userID
    JOIN (SELECT a.userID, a.purchaseTime 
            FROM fsl a WHERE a.purchaseTime = 
            (SELECT MIN(b.purchaseTime) FROM fsl b WHERE b.userID = a.userID)) trd
    ON trd.userID = snd.userID;
```

However, I can't make any guarantee that this is going to be fast enough for any sort of production use.

Comment: thank you for giving me help. the response time is not the first priority for me in this moment, I will take time to study the answer you gave, thanks!